# Android Push Notification Server Implementation

Tags: android, push-notification, mqtt, atmosphere

I am thinking one of the following technologies to use to build an Android Push Notification Server (not to use Google Cloud Messaging/GCM neither FCM):

- Atmosphere Framework (http://async-io.org/)
- Eclipse Mosquitto (https://mosquitto.org/)

The overall goal of this project is to allow Android application using the Custom Android Push Notification server be able to receive and display notification like this:

[image]

The first question would be: *if an Android application does not utilize GCM or FCM would it be able to display notifications similar to those that use GCM or FCM?*

Then if we use either the *Atmosphere Framework* or the *Eclipse Mosquitto* as a Push Notification Server would it be able to send push notification on an Android device without relying on GCM or FCM?

Also, I assume that if not using GCM or FCM then it is not possible for the registered Android device to receive a push notification from the custom APN server if the application that uses the custom APN is not running? This is correct, right? If so, then what would be the work-around? Make sure the Android application is running in the background?

Comment: How is this different from your last question?

Comment: Just for knowledge sake, can you please tell me why you are not using FCM for this purpose? Is there any specific advantage of the other technologies mentioned?

Comment: @DerrylThomas for research work

Comment: @xybrek..great! Good luck! Do let me know in case you find any better alternative. I spent a while on this and ended up sticking with FCM.